# Parse L2TP in PCAP++

Tags: c++, pcapplusplus

I need to parse difficult traffic with `Layer 2 Tunneling Protocol`:
`Eth->IP->UDP->L2TP->PTPP->IP->TCP->...`
.. and get inner and outer IP addresses.
I use loop over `layer->getNextLayer())` and it stops after first UDP.
Is there any BestPractise to cope with L2TP?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is because L2TP isn't supported by PcapPlusPlus. Unfortunately there's no way around it, but to add support for it. Would you consider implementing it?

Comment: @seladb, yes, I will try to implement it